# Can't access array in other functions

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I have made an NSArray following a tutorial on lynda.com. Maybe the tutorial is a little old but when I create an array in viewDidLoad i cannot access it in

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

function so i moved it from viewDidLoad into this function and now i cannot access it in the prepare for segue function so i had to recreate the array for what i want to do to work. Is this what is supposed to happen?

Comment: You need to include the code you're actually asking about.  It sounds most likely though that you're creating a local array when you need an instance variable.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/eraJBVfC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create property in @interface, like:

```
@interface SettingsViewController ()
    @property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *settings;
@end
```

This creates you a variable you can use in your whole class (its private, tho). TO access it (getter/setter), you then type `self.settings`.
Then instead of creating your array in `cellForRow..`, just add your settings in `viewDidLoad`, e.g.:

```
self.settings = [NSMutableArray new];

Settings *settingsStar = [Settings new];
settingsStar.name = @"Rate the App";
[self.settings addObject:settingsStar];

Settings *settingsShare = [Settings new];
settingsShare.name = @"Tell Your Friends";
[self.settings addObject:settingsShare];

...
```

To make your code more clear, you can even use it with for loop, based on array, like:

```
self.settings = [NSMutableArray new];
NSArray *settingsNames = @[@"Rate the App", @"Tell Your Friends"];
for (NSString *setting in settingsNames) {
    Settings *newSettings = [Settings new];
    newSettings.name = setting;
    [self.settings addObject:newSettings];
}
```